# Regression: Variable influence

Tags: python, sas, regression

Is there any way in SAS , Python to find the most influential variables in rank order apart from correlation ?

I might be missing something and any suggestion would be appreciated how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

In SAS, apart from the correlation (Pearson index) you can use a ranking index like the Spearman coefficient (proc corr).
In addition, supposing you have the correct modules (STAT/MINER) licensed you can use:

- a linear (logistic) regression on standardized regressors and compare the betas
- a tree and compare the variables on one of the available metrics (Gini, Chi2)